# How to retrieve text input value and id with a button click in a window with multiple text inputs and buttons

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an application with multiple tabs, text inputs and buttons. The value and id of the text input will eventually be stored in the data structure. I am stuck trying to retrieve the value and id of a specific input field on a button click.

The id is logged just fine on enter but I can't get it to work on click.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="Materials" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Materials</h3>
  <p>List of materials and prices</p> 
    <p>Add a new board size:</p>
    <input type="text" class="addNew board" id = "newBoardSize">
    <button class="add board">Add</button>
    <p>Add a new wood type:</p>
    <input type="text" class="addNew wood" id = "newWoodType">
    <button class="add wood">Add</button>   
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS

```
//attaching event handler to all buttons
let buttonEl = document.querySelectorAll(".add");
for (var i=0; i< buttonEl.length; i++){
    buttonEl[i].addEventListener('click', addItem); 
};

//attach event handler to all text input fields - adding item on enter

let inputEl = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var i=0; i< inputEl.length; i++){
    inputEl[i].addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        addItem (this.id);
    }
    })
};

function addItem(type) {
            console.log(type)
        };
```

How do i tie the button and the text input field together dynamically without hardcoding the id's for every button? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you nest your input and button in its own div, it'll be easier to do `let thisInput = buttonEl[i].closest('input')` then do some stuff with that like `inputId = thisInput.id` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, you can get this modyfing the buttons `for loop` like this:

```
for (var i=0; i< buttonEl.length; i++){
    buttonEl[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      addItem(document.querySelector('input.' + this.classList[1]).id)
      // It gets the second class of the button
    }); 
};
```

It used the same common `class` in `button` and `input`. So it will return dynamically the `id`, in this case, or anything you want from the `input` clicking on `button`.

Hope it helps.